# How to format data type in R without hardcoding them

Tags: r

I trying to get a dataframe which I get the data from an API call. Now based on the columns wer get I am recoding each of the column to `character` , `date` or `numeric` . Is their a way where we can recode these columns rather than hard coding them each time.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This function will attempt to find the best type for each vec:

```
df <- type.convert(df)
```

This variant will convert factors to strings:

```
df <- data.frame(type.convert(df), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I think it is generally safer to coerce data types on individual vectors comprising a dataframe e.g:

```
df$character_vec_1 <- as.character(df$integer_vec_1)
```